# How to use 'AnimatedModalBarrier' in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I didn't find any example for constructor `AnimatedModalBarrier`.
Don't know how to use this widget like modalbarrier.

> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedModalBarrier-class.html

```
const AnimatedModalBarrier({
  Key key,
  Animation<Color> color,
  this.dismissible = true,
  this.semanticsLabel,
  this.barrierSemanticsDismissible,
}) : super(key: key, listenable: color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `AnimatedModalBarrier` works by disabling interactions with the widgets behind itself, the common implementation is using a `Stack`. For example you want to disable interactions with `FormWidget`, the modal barrier must be placed above the `FormWidget`

```
Stack(
  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    FormWidget,
    _animatedModalBarrier
  ],
)
```

To create the `AnimatedModalBarrier` itself,you need to create an `Animation<Color>`. You can use `ColorTween` to create the animation

```
ColorTween  _colorTween = ColorTween(
  begin: Color.red
  end: Color.blue,
);

AnimationController _animationController = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 1)
);
Animation<Color> _colorTweenAnimation = _colorTween.animate(_animationController);

_animatedModalBarrier = AnimatedModalBarrier(
  color: _colorTweenAnimation
);
```

Source & Full Code: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-animatedmodalbarrier-examples